# How can I make the game's save file encoded in some form?

Tags: lua, save, love2d

I want to make a save for my game. (It's not just a kind of save that saves coins and stuff it's saves the selected character and etc.) But it's too easy to cheese and rewrite and do everything you want with it.

I want it to be less easy for the user to change things in the save file.

My first idea was to decode and encode it to base64 but it was still way too easy to crack.

If somebody would ask the save file is technically a txt file renamed to save.dat which is just for organization reasons.

Comment: [Simple encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35732880/20468470)

Comment: You could use a binary serializing format alltogether, e.g. [MessagePack](https://github.com/kieselsteini/msgpack). It's still readable, but the binary mess usually scares people off, and those really interested will decode it anyways.